# Translate default message No data available in v-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I would like to translate the default message No data found in `v-autocomplete` when the search returns nothing. I understand it is due to default behaviour, but my app supports multiple languages through [i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) localization library, so I would like to make it fully localized.

Sample code is for the autocomplete component:

```
<v-autocomplete
                class="form-select__region"
                :class="fieldName"
                dense
                :disabled="disabled"
                item-text="text"
                item-value="value"
                :items="getData"
                outlined
                single-line
                solo
                :value="value"
                @change="input(fieldName, $event)"
            >
            </v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to use the slot 'no-data' like this :

```
<template v-slot:no-data>
   <div class="px-4">YOUR TEXT</div>
</template>
```